# Compiling java code and creating jar online

Tags: java, java-7, jdk1.4

My problem: I have JDK 1.7 version on my machine. The jar I created with this does not run on my Unix machine as it has JRE 1.4 installed (I don't have admin rights to this machine).

So, is there a way to compile my code with version 1.4 w/o uninstalling 1.7 on my machine. Can it be done online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [-target version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html) option to perform cross-compilation.

Example as per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html)

> % javac -target 1.4 -bootclasspath jdk1.4.2/lib/classes.zip \
>                -extdirs "" OldCode.java

Answer (score 0):

According to the [javac documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html), you can set the JDK source using -source parameter:

```
javac -source 1.4 MyClass
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://ideone.com/) ,[this](http://rextester.com/runcode) and [this](http://www.onlinecompiler.net/) are very good sites where you can run all your java code online and get the results, without having JDK installed in your machine

Comment: this doesn't answer the question.